# Laravel 4.2 + Laravel + PHP 7 +Ubuntu= Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I've just installed Laravel and it's awesome working with Laravel 5.2 but I need to work with a project made in Laravel 4.2 and I can't run any "php artisan" command that I have "Mcrypt PHP extension required." error!

I'm using ubuntu + vagrant + laravel

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why? Probably because php7.0-mcrypt is not installed.

Comment: i installed sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt

Comment: i can't enabled it

Comment: restarting apache might help sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: not still the problem